# Stage not showing in Spark UI

Tags: apache-spark

I have written a program in Spark, which has the following details:

```
Line Number    Job                              Showing in Spark UI(yes/No)
----------------------------------------------------
56             lines.count()                     yes
82             blockMap.count()                  yes
67             blockMap=lines.mapToPair          yes
85             block=blockMap.groupByKey         no
87             block.count()                     yes
122            map2.count()                      yes
90             map2=block.flatMapToPair          yes
192            reduce1.count()                   No
128            reduce1=map2.groupByKey.mapToPair No
226            result.count()                    yes
199            result=reduce1.map                No
```

Why all the jobs are not showing in the Spark UI? Also, why count() is running before the actual RDD actions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not showing in the UI here? How are you able to see the plan broken into stages and not see each stage in the UI? It would be helpful if you could provide code and/or a graphic of the execution in this case. Also, a note for your last question, the stage number order does not imply the order of scheduling.

Comment: They are not the stage number, they are the line number in my program

Comment: UI showing the stage progress bar indicating the line number of my program. I have given the count() after each action and transformation in the code. Therefore, I thought each action and its corresponding count should be shown in the UI as progressing.